# Upgrade to PHP 7 on Mac

Tags: php, bash, macos, curl

I was trying to follow the instructions to upgrade to PHP 7 on Mac on https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/.

I used this command:
    `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0`

And got this result:

```
Detected OS X El Capitan 10.11. All ok.
Get packager.tgz
Unpack packager.tgz
Please type in your password, as we want to install this into /usr/local
Password:
Start packager (may take some time)
  File "/usr/local/packager/packager.py", line 38
    print "ERROR: Option %s is not valid for command %s\n" % (opt[0], command)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

Use homebrew > http://brew.sh/

Install homebrew by running `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Then install PHP7 by running

`brew install homebrew/php/php70`

When done, add `export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php70)/bin:$PATH"` into your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

This process has been simplified; the above answer will give you
"homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated."

All you need to type now is

```
brew install php
```

Or

```
brew install php composer
```